# Ant antcall a target that defines a property

Tags: ant

In Ant I want to define a target (called `A`) that define a property and `antcall` it from another target (called `B`). I want that the target `B`, after antcalling the target `A`, can access the property defined in the target `A`.

For example:

```
<target name="B">
    <antcall target="A" inheritAll="true" inheritRefs="true" />
    <echo>${myprop}</echo>
</target>
<target name="A">
    <property name="myprop" value="myvalue" />
</target>
```

However it doesn't work and `<echo>${myprop}</echo>` doesn't print `myvalue` (I think because the property `myprop` isn't defined in `B`).

Is there any way to do that?

Comment: Would you mind checking your question? You probably didn't intend to have have B calling B.

Comment: @rajah9: I want to define the property in target A, and echo it in target B. The target A is called from the target B. The main problem is that I want to create a target and divide it into subtargets.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

According to the [Apache Ant FAQ](http://ant.apache.org/faq.html):

```
    <target name="cond" depends="cond-if"/>

    <target name="cond-if" if="prop1">
      <antcall target="cond-if-2"/>
    </target>

    <target name="cond-if-2" if="prop2">
      <antcall target="cond-if-3"/>
    </target>

    <target name="cond-if-3" unless="prop3">
      <echo message="yes"/>
    </target>
```

`Note: <antcall> tasks do not pass property changes back up to the environment they were called from, so you wouldn't be able to, for example, set a result property in the cond-if-3 target, then do <echo message="result is ${result}"/> in the cond target.`

In this respect, it is **impossible** to do what you want using antcall.

========== **edit** ===========

Try `antcallback`: AntCallBack is identical to the standard 'antcall' task, except that it allows properties set in the called target to be available in the calling target.
http://antelope.tigris.org/nonav/docs/manual/bk03ch20.html

Sample code pasted from the above page:

```
    <target name="testCallback" description="Test CallBack">
        <taskdef name="antcallback" classname="ise.antelope.tasks.AntCallBack" classpath="${antelope.home}/build" />
        <antcallback target="-testcb" return="a, b"/>
        <echo>a = ${a}</echo>
        <echo>b = ${b}</echo>
    </target>

    <target name="-testcb">
        <property name="a" value="A"/>
        <property name="b" value="B"/>
    </target>
```

Comment: Thanks. It was the issue. How do you implement that behaviour in a different way? I mean I would like to divide the logic of a target into subtargets

Comment: Also, you can try task 'AntCallBack' from Ant-Contrib package: http://ant-contrib.sourceforge.net/tasks/tasks/index.html

Answer (score 9):

Another approach is to refactor your targets into macros. You are trying to use targets like functions and they are just not intended to be used that way. I typically write the bulk of my logic as macros, so that I can compose it more easily into more complicated macros. Then I write simple wrapper targets for the command-line entry points that I need.

Comment: This is the best approach.  ant properties are not variables, they're immutable.  an antcall into the same build.xml _always_ smells bad.

Answer (score 5):

Rather than using `<antcall>`, **why not just have target B depend on target A**?

```
<target name="B" depends="A">
    <echo>${myprop}</echo>
</target>
<target name="A">
    <property name="myprop" value="myvalue" />
</target>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to use a param.

```
<project default="B">
<target name="B">
    <antcall target="A">
      <param name="myprop" value="myvalue"/>
    </antcall>

</target>
<target name="A">
    <echo>${myprop}</echo>
</target>
</project>
```

I surrounded this with a project tag and moved the echo statement into "A". My output says

```
B:
A:
     [echo] myvalue
BUILD SUCCESSFUL
```

Comment: That is `not` what OP wants. He wants to define the property in target A, and echo it in target B. Here, you define it in A and echo it in A.

Answer (score 0):

@alem0lars, since you said you would like to subdivide a target, let me offer a different solution (that unfortunately doesn't answer your original question).

```
<project default="mytarg">
<target name="mytarg">
  <property name="tgt" value="build"/>
  <antcall target="deps"/>
</target>
<target name="deps" depends="aTgt,bTgt"/>
<target name="aTgt">
  <echo>"In aTgt doing a ${tgt}"</echo>
</target>
<target name="bTgt">
  <echo>"In bTgt doing a ${tgt}"</echo>
</target>
</project>
```

This subdivides the build into aTgt and bTgt.

Output will be

```
aTgt:
     [echo] "In aTgt doing a build"
bTgt:
     [echo] "In bTgt doing a build"
deps:
BUILD SUCCESSFUL
```