# Ant Task scope - name is undefined

Tags: ant

I have read this post:
[Ant antcall a target that defines a property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5275682/ant-antcall-a-target-that-defines-a-property)

This question is talking about properties. I would like to know how can I make `<taskdef>` on inner target that could be used for all project.

I don't want to define it on my main target, since it could be long and ugly. That's why i like to split it to inner targets.
The error i get is:

```
Cause: The name is undefined.
Action: Check the spelling.
Action: Check that any custom tasks/types have been declared.
Action: Check that any <presetdef>/<macrodef> declarations have taken place.
```

Comment: This error appears incomplete. If I'm correct, it's the error message you get when missing the jar belonging to a 3rd party ANT task.

Answer (score 1):

You want to call a target which defines a property, and use that property in the caller-scope, right?

You should take a look at ant contrib's `RunTarget`: http://ant-contrib.sourceforge.net/tasks/tasks/runtarget.html.